# 'no Access-Control-Allow-Origin in the request header

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-core, cors, fetch-api

I have created an API with ASP.NET Core, in Program.cs I specified the allowed origins policy as shown:

```
var origins = 'allowedOrigins';
builder.Services.AddCors((options) => {
  options.AddPolicy(origins, (policy) => {
    policy
      .WithOrigins(
        'http://10.9.8.50:80',
        'http://10.9.8.50:81',
        'http://10.9.8.50:7087',
        'http://10.9.8.50:5000'
      )
      .AllowAnyHeader()
      .AllowAnyMethod();
  });
});

app.UseCors(origins);
```

and I am using basic JavaScript fetch method to call POST

```
async function postData(url = '', data = {}) {
  let value;
  const p = await fetch(url, {
    method: 'POST',
    mode: 'cors',
    cache: 'no-cache',
    credentials: 'same-origin',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
    redirect: 'follow',
    referrerPolicy: 'no-referrer',
    body: JSON.stringify(data),
  }).then((response) => (value = response.text()));
  return value;
}
```

recently, the server starting to act weird after I tried to publish some modifications to the logic of one of the controllers. I started getting 'no  Access-Control-Allow-Origin in the request header'.

I am working with IIS 10 server, I tried to inject the CORS policy in the web.config but I started getting an error saying only one value was allowed in  Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

I am wondering what might be the issue that started all of this, and what could the solution be.

Thanks

EDIT: I added the following lines to my web.config file

```
<cors enabled="true" failUnlistedOrigins="false">
        <add origin="*" allowed="true" />
</cors>
```

And now I am getting the following error:

> has been blocked by CORS policy: Request header field content-type is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.

Comment: This row: `var origins = "allowedOrigins";` Aren't you supposed to write the origins here, and not have the text "allowedOrigins"?

Comment: @some: I think that's just the policy name.

Comment: @PoulBak Oh. It's hard to read when the indentation is off and not all code is inside the code block.

Comment: Yeah, it's just the name

Comment: @Alaa I reformated the code to make it more readable, and included `app.UseCors(origins);` in the block of code. If that's not what you want, then you can revert the edit. EDIT: Oops, I accidentally changes all double quotes to single qutoes.

Comment: @some that looks good, thank you. the quotes are not a problem I have them the correct way. However, does the issue make any sense to you, please ?

Comment: I think this happens when setting both in your startup code and in webconfig... then you return two Access-Control-Allow-Origin headers.  (remove the webconfig stuff, OR the startup code)

Comment: @pcalkins right now I don't have anything in the webconfig, it's just in the startup program.

Comment: Are you accessing the server at one of the addresses that you specified in the policy? Is it the browser that complains about the "no Access-Control-Allow-Origin in the request header"?

Comment: I think you've got some extra parenthesis here: builder.Services.AddCors((options) => {
  options.AddPolicy(origins, (policy)  ... maybe try: builder.Services.AddCors(options => {
  options.AddPolicy(origins, policy => ...

Comment: Bye the way, you set ` referrerPolicy: "no-referrer"`.  Doesn't that block the required `origin` header? Shouldn't it be `origin-when-cross-origin`?

Comment: @pcalkins Those "extra" parenthesis is around the argument for the arrow function. While it can be omitted for a single argument, it is required if more than one element is specified. It isn't an error to include them when a single argument is given. It is actually preferred to include them even when it is a single argument.

Comment: @some I believe it is the browser because I can't see any errors in the event viewer on the server, it works also when testing with Postman, I changed the referrer to the suggested one, but that didn't help either.
And yes, I am making the call from one of the domains provided.

Comment: ah, ok...  referrer should be separate from origin, so I don't think that's it.  I would check the server's response in your browser's dev tools.  The error suggests that you are getting two headers.  Not sure why you've set that redirect option (it's default anyway) but any request that responds with a redirect wouldn't work for pre-flight request.  (I think you'd see a different error if that were the case though...)

Comment: at the moment, I only have the policy in my startup program, nothing on the server and the error in the console coming back as:
"has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled."

I tried to use no-cors but then I am not able to pass json objects

Comment: @Alaa Since you wrote that your server was acting strange:  Have you tried to turn it off and then on again? Yes, I'm serious :)

Comment: 'no-cors' won't turn off the browser's CORS rules.  It sorta means "I don't need a response from this cross-origin simple request..."  However, this request is triggering a pre-flight check (fetch w/json, not simple request).  The "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource." means that the server has not responded correctly to the pre-flight OPTIONS request.  The other error "only one value was allowed in Access-Control-Allow-Origin" suggests the server is responding but with two headers present.  Those are separate cases/causes.

Comment: @some, that didn't help.

Comment: @pclkins, are you suggesting that there is a problem with the server ? but it is still working right now if I try to test it with Postman. So I don't think it's a server's issue.

Comment: Please check the edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding the following lines to my API's web.config file solved the problem.

```
<cors enabled="true" failUnlistedOrigins="false">
    <add origin="*" allowed="true">
        <allowHeaders allowAllRequestedHeaders="true"/>
    </add>
</cors>
```